# Время обновления DNS

Tags: dns

Как долго обновляются записи в DNS? Я заметил, что при изменении записей типа A или CNAME проходит иногда до суток, в зависимости от того, откуда они проверяются? Есть ли верхняя граница по времени?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Верхнего времени нет и в принципе не может быть в силу распределенной организации DNS серверов. Вот представьте себе, что сервер, где изменные данные лег, не успев обновить информацию на соседях. По минимальному времени - что-то в районе считанных часов.

Answer (score 1):

Время обновления зависит от параметра TTL (Time to live), который определяет свежесть данных при кэшировании запросов. Этот параметр обычно выставляют в сутки, но вообще он может меняться в широких пределах.